# ¿Mostrar una subconsulta en html?

Tags: php, mysql

mi pregunta es esa, como puedo mostrar una subconsulta en HTML, con un . Son dos tablas que tienen Tipo de artículo y la otra el subtipo de artículo.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tipo_Productos (
cod_tipo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Tipo TEXT,
Sub_Tipo TEXT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Producto(
    cod_producto VARCHAR(500) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT,
    cod_tipo INT,
    Descripcion TEXT,
    Cantidad VARCHAR(500),
    Precio DECIMAL(10,2),
    FOREIGN KEY(codigocliente)REFERENCES cliente(codigocliente)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Subtipos_Productos(
cod_subtipo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
cod_tipo INT,
Descripcion_Subtipo VARCHAR(500)
```

);

Ese es el código MYSQL.
El caso es que lo quiero mostrar en una página html con , en la tabla Tipo_productos tendrá 1- CD, y en la segunda Tabla 1-1-Verbatin. Pero no se como realizarlo. La consulta para mostrar los datos es:

```
SELECT tipo_productos.Tipo, subtipos_productos.Tipo FROM subtipos_productos, tipo_productos WHERE subtipos_productos.cod_tipo = tipo_productos.cod_tipo;
```

Alguna idea de como mostrarlos?

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar los datos en HTML tendrás que incluir código PHP en el HTML y utilizar mysqli para acceder a la base de datos. Envíame tu HTML y te lo añado, no es complicado.

Con respecto a la consulta, estás usando el campo Tipo en vez de Descripcion_Subtipo, observa que en la tabla de subtipos no tienes el campo Tipo.

```
SELECT
  Tipo_Productos.Tipo,
  Subtipos_Productos.Descripcion_Subtipo
FROM Subtipos_Productos,
     Tipo_Productos
WHERE Subtipos_Productos.cod_tipo = Tipo_Productos.cod_tipo;
```

Por otra parte, estás resolviendo esta consulta a través de un producto cartesiano. Te recomiendo utilizar el producto interno, con el que obtendrás el mismo resultado, pero de forma mucho más eficiente:

```
SELECT
  Tipo_Productos.Tipo,
  Subtipos_Productos.Descripcion_Subtipo
FROM Subtipos_Productos JOIN Tipo_Productos
USING(cod_tipo);
```